# pandas groupby() with custom aggregate function and put result in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I want to group it by one of the columns and compute a new value for each group using a custom aggregate function.

This new value has a totally different meaning and its column just is not present in the original dataframe. So, in effect, I want to change the shape of the dataframe during the `groupby() + agg()` transformation. The original dataframe looks like `(foo, bar, baz)` and has a range index while the resulting dataframe needs to have only `(qux)` column and `baz` as an index.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'baz': [0, 0, 1]})
df.head()

#        foo    bar    baz
#   0      1      a      0
#   1      2      b      0
#   2      3      c      1    

def calc_qux(gdf, **kw):
    qux = ','.join(map(str, gdf['foo'])) + ''.join(gdf['bar'])
    return (None, None)  # but I want (None, None, qux)

df = df.groupby('baz').agg(calc_qux, axis=1)  # ['qux'] but then it fails, since 'qux' is not presented in the frame.
df.head()

#      qux
# baz       
#   0  1,2ab
#   1  3c
```

The code above produces an error `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 3), indices imply (2, 2)` if I'm trying to return from the aggregation function different amount of values than the number of columns in the original dataframe.

Comment: What is your desired output exactly?

Comment: Without the expected output, not sure I understand. But you probably want to `apply` rather than aggregate, and probably want to return a `pd.Series` instead of a `tuple`

Comment: @rahlf23 just added an example, please check the updated question.

Comment: @RafaelC `apply + series` with single value might work, but I still need a group by step. Can I group by while applying something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use `apply()` here since you are not operating on a single column (in which case `agg()` would be appropriate):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'baz': [0, 0, 1]})

def calc_qux(x):

    return ','.join(x['foo'].astype(str).values) + ''.join(x['bar'].values)

df.groupby('baz').apply(calc_qux).to_frame('qux')
```

Yields:

```
       qux
baz       
0    1,2ab
1       3c
```

Comment: This solution looks great. However, such usage of the `apply()` looks counterintuitive to me. Each group might have up to N values and the goal is to reduce them to one _aggregated_ value, i.e. _reduce_. While my understanding of the `apply()` was that it's something like a _map_.

Comment: `apply()` simply applies a prescribed function (in this case `calc_qux`) to every 'sub-dataframe' that is passed (in this case, every group from `df.groupby('baz')`). `apply()` also functions column-wise and row-wise depending on the `axis` argument when applying directly to a dataframe